# error when trying to Change the ios app name. I have followed different examples but its not working- react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to change my apps name. I have followed a few different solutions but i am getting an error.

I changed the name in the info.plist and then i did a yarn and i did a pod install in the ios folder. I also deleted the app from my simulator and then built it again but I am still getting the following error:

Invariant Violation: "[old app name]" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed app name in `index.js` or `index.ios.js` and `App.json` files. Which are located in root folder of project.

index.js:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourAppNewName', () => App)
```

App.json:

```
{ "name": "YourAppNewName", "displayName": "YourAppNewName" }
```

Comment: Sorted thanks. I ended up having to do it though xcode then everything was fine